# Указатель на массив C++

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Пусть имеем статический массив:

```
short tell[20];
```

Где:

1. `tell` - адрес первого элемента массива (2-байтный блок).
2. `&tell` - адрес целого массива (40-байтный блок).

И имеется следующая конструкция, указывающая на массив из 20 элементов типа short:

```
short (*pas)[20] = &tell
```

Получившимся типом данных переменной pas является тип: `short (*)[20]`. Собственно вопрос, как создать переменную данного типа, и выделить ей память при помощи операции new?

Пример взят из книги: Стивен Прата - Язык программирования C++ (6 издание). Стр. 182.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если у вас есть объявление массива вида

```
T a[N];
```

где `T` - это некоторый тип, а `N` - это число элементов в массиве, то указатель на первый элемент массива будет иметь тип `T *`. Например

```
T *p = a;
```

После этого определения указатель `p` указывает на первый элемент массива `a`.

Чтобы выделить динамически память для массива, аналогичного массиву, определенному выше, вы можете записать

```
T *p = new T[N];
```

Здесь элемент массива имеет тип `T`, а `p` как и выше показывает на первый элемент динамически выделенного безыменного массива..

Теперь представим, что `T` это алиас для типа `short[20]`, например

```
typedef short T[20];
```

Тогда ранее показанные объявления для указателя могут быть записаны как

```
T *p = &a;
```

и

```
T *p = new T[1];
```

Если снова вернуться к исходному типу `short[20]`, то получим

```
short( *p )[20] = &a;
```

и

```
short( *p )[20] = new short[1][20];
```

Последнее предложение означает, что выделяется массив из одного элемента (вы можете выделять массив из произвольного числа элементов в соответствии с вашей задачей), элементами которого в свою очередь являются массивы из 20 элементов типа `short`.

Имейте в виду, что когда используется так называемая арифметика указателей, то значение указателя меняется на значение кратное `sizeof( T )`

Поэтому если вы, например, объявите указатель как

```
short( *p )[20] = &a;
```

где `T` эквивалентно `short[20]`, то после применения, например, инкремента к этому указателю

```
++p;
```

указатель будет содержать адрес сразу же после последнего элемента массива `a`.

Ну, и напоследок пример работы с таким указателем.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iterator>

const size_t N = 20;

short ( * create_2D_array( size_t n ) )[N]
{
    short ( *p )[N] = new short[n][N];

    return p;
}   

int main() 
{
    short a[N];

    std::iota( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), 1 );

    for ( short x : a ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    short ( *p )[N] = create_2D_array( 1 );

    std::iota( std::reverse_iterator<short *>( *p + N ), 
               std::reverse_iterator<short *>( *p ), 1 );

    for ( short x : *p ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::swap( a, *p );

    for ( short x : a ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( short x : *p ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete [] p;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 

20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, достаточно качественное объяснение именно того, что требовалось.

Answer (score 4):

Вообще-то и `tell`, и `&tell[0]`, и `&tell` - это все одна и та же сущность, адрес, с которого начинается блок памяти, выделенный для массива...

```
typedef short array[20];
short * a = new array;
```

Здесь мы описываем тип массива из 20 `short`, и создаем его динамически, возвращая указатель на начало блока с ним. Работаем с ним, как с обычным массивом, типа

```
for(short i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
{
    a[i] = i;
}
```

Comment: Ну естественно, при выводе адреса, мы получим одинаковые значения. Но вот что при добавлении 1 к tell и &tell даст разный результат, а именно произойдет увеличение значений адресов на разные величины.

Comment: @IXD Тогда я не понял вопрос. Можно как-то его подробнее задать?

Comment: @Harry Вопрос собственно не в том, как создать обычный динамический массив типа short, а возможность создания переменной типа short (*)[20] описывающей массив 20 элементов типа short. Где при инкременте указателя на 1, мы получим увеличение адреса не на 2 единицы, а на 20.

Comment: Возможно прояснит ситуацию статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/251091/ с подпунктом "Указатель на массив". Однако там не рассматривается мой вопрос о создании переменной определенного типа.

Comment: @IXD Ну вот, смотрите - `    short * t = new short[20];

    array * a = reinterpret_cast<array*>(t);

    printf("%p %p %p\n",a,a+1,a+2);` Как видите, `a` указывает именно на массив; `a+1` прыгает на 40 байт... Это то, что вы хотели?

Comment: Нет. Меня интересует именно создание переменной short (*)[20] и последующее выделение памяти именно ей. Без предварительного создания динамического массива и использования конструкции reinterpret_cast. К тому же, вывод вашего printf показывает различия не одинаковой длины: 0x1717c20 0x1717c48 0x1717c70 (28 и 22 байта).

Comment: Для наглядности: Однако следующий вывод дает именно желаемые результат с разницей в 40 байт:
    short tell[20];
    cout << &tell + 1 << endl;
    cout << &tell + 2 << endl;
    cout << &tell + 3 << endl;
    cout << &tell + 4 << endl;
    Вывод: 0x7ffe6f6555a8                                                      
    0x7ffe6f6555d0                                                      
    0x7ffe6f6555f8                                                      
    0x7ffe6f655620

Comment: Ну, `cout << typeid(a).name() << endl;` выдает именно `short(*)[20]`. Т.е. переменную желаемого типа мы получили. Что касается более глубокого закапывания в массивы с использованием текста стандарта, то тут могу только посоветовать обратиться к более опытным специалистам - я настолько стандарт не знаю.

Comment: Говорить, что `tell` и `&tell[0]` - одна и та же сущность, неверно. Во-первых, в чистом виде `tell` - это lvalue типа "массив", а  `&tell[0]` - это rvalue типа "указатель", т.е. между ними вообще мало общего. Во-вторых, даже в тех контекстах, где происходит *array type decay* и `tell` рассмативается как указатель (эквивалентный `&tell[0]`), все равно како-то странно назвать их "одной и той же сущностью". Rvalues - сущности эфемерные, своей адресной идентичности почти не имеющие, по каковой причине трудно говорить, одна и та же у нас тут сущность или две похожие, но разные.